# Restrict reverse geolocating - kCLErrorDomain Code=2

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, gps, reverse-geocoding

I am currently trying to write an iOS app that logs the states that a user has visited.

The issue I am facing is that my `(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` method is being called over and over again. I don't necessarily see this as an issue except in that method, I am calling another method that reverse geocodes the CLLocation object and gives the state name.

The error I am getting is:

```
Geocode failed with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)"
```

I understand that I am reaching the limit on reverseGeoCoding over a certain timelimit, I am just not sure how to limit it.

Here is my code:

```
CLLocation *currentLocation;

- (void) getLocation
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {

         if (error){
             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
             return;

         }

         if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark= [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             currentState = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[placemark administrativeArea]];
         }

         //Checks to see if the state exists in the textFile, if not it writes it to the file
         if(![newState checkIfStateExists:currentState])
         {
             [newState writeToFile:currentState];
         }

     }];
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    //just a thought, didn't work
    //if(![[locations lastObject] isEqual:currentLocation])

        currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
        [self getLocation];

}

-(void) initializeGPS
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self initializeGPS];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

This code works perfectly in the fact that it gets the location in GPS coordinates, translates it into a state name, and writes that state name to a file.

It is just being called too many times, and I am unsure how to limit the number of times that `(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the distanceFilter property of the CLLocationManager as outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

the distanceFilter property allows you to set the distance in meters the device must travel before the location is updated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't realize I could do this!

Comment: I do have one question. when I run StartUpdatingLocation, will it initially run one time to get my current location?

Comment: Yes it will, as long as it is a new instance of the CLLocationManager.