# CLGeocoder.ReverseGecode hangs after 50 requests

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, core-location

First my code:

```
private CLGeocoder _coder = new CLGeocoder();

private void TestWithTpl()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test started");
    var testLocation = new CLLocation(52.268157,-1.4209);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
    {
        for (var i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting iteration {0}", i);
            var res = await _coder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync(testLocation);
            Console.WriteLine(res[0].AdministrativeArea);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished iteration {0}", i);
        }
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}

private void TestDefault()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test started");
    var testLocation = new CLLocation(52.268157,-1.4209);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        for (var i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting iteration {0}", i);
            var res = _coder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync(testLocation).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(res[0].AdministrativeArea);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished iteration {0}", i);
        }
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

As you can see, TestWithTpl will make use of async and await while TestDefault just uses the Result of the ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync.

No matter which method of the both I use: The output will be something like this:

```
2013-10-11 12:05:54.882 AddressResolveTest[5290:a0b] Test started
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
2013-10-11 12:05:54.892 AddressResolveTest[5290:a0b] Finished
2013-10-11 12:05:54.897 AddressResolveTest[5290:6303] Starting iteration 0
2013-10-11 12:05:55.125 AddressResolveTest[5290:6303] England
2013-10-11 12:05:55.126 AddressResolveTest[5290:6303] Finished iteration 0
2013-10-11 12:05:55.127 AddressResolveTest[5290:6303] Starting iteration 1
...
2013-10-11 12:05:57.302 AddressResolveTest[5290:6303] Finished iteration 49
2013-10-11 12:05:57.302 AddressResolveTest[5290:6303] Starting iteration 50
```

After the last line nothing happens.

I don't know, why:

1. "Finished" is written before the code is ready.
2. The code **always** stops at request no. 50.

Comment: The 2nd case "TestDefault" shouldn't print "Finished" before starting. But for the first case, it's definitely normal.

Comment: I think that's because you are abusing the CLGeocoder. Quote from Apple docs: "...you should not send more than one geocoding request per minute."

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos: You are right! But that isn't helpful because no geo-based app listens to this advice. Take Runtastic as an exampel! How would you create an app that takes care of this advice?

Comment: They are probably not relying on Apple's GeoCoding service.

Comment: @Jason But what then? Resolving on the server? Thats what I gonna do, but it's comming with huge amount of infrastructure. Would be interesting to know for me :-).

Comment: They are either providing their own service, or using someone else's.  Google "reverse geocode" to find some alternate providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. "Finished" should be printed at the start, at least for the TPL version, as `StartNew()` start a task in the background, and the execution continue. It shouldn't be the case for the "Default" version. could you check ?
2. the problem is that StartNew() swallows exceptions. If you change your code like this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Test started");
var testLocation = new CLLocation(52.268157,-1.4209);
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
    {
        try{
            for (var i=0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting iteration {0}", i);
                var res = await _coder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync(testLocation);
                Console.WriteLine(res[0].AdministrativeArea);
                Console.WriteLine("Finished iteration {0}", i);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine (e);
        }
    });
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
```

you'll be able to get the `Exception` with the message: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)`

Googling for this message gets you a lot of hits here on stackoverflow, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310883/restrict-reverse-geolocating-kclerrordomain-code-2) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867422/kclerrordomain-error-2-after-geocoding-repeatedly-with-clgeocoder). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620181/1063783) even announce the same '50' limit you get.

At the end, I'd say Apple limit the amount of request you can do per minute, and even [recommend you not to overuse the API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Applications should be conscious of how they use geocoding. Here are
> some rules of thumb for using this class effectively:
>
> **Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. IT worked. You now, what I don't understand? Why are those hints not pointed out more clear? The advice "one request per minute" is nonsens in my eyes.

Comment: There's certainly a reason (good or bad) behind that, like preserve battery or avoid military usage, but it's unclear indeed.